# Disabling some modules installed via a feature

Tags: 7, features

Is it possible to disable a module that was installed via a feature?

For example, I'm using a theme that came with a feature that installed a lot of modules, I realized that I don't need a bunch of the modules, but I can't disable them in the module page (the 'enabled' checkbox can't be toggled anymore).

Is it possible to just remove the feature but keep each individual modules configuration?

Comment: It's a bit risky if you don't understand the dependency tree fully, but just try it on a local copy, and you'll find out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can’t.

But, if you are 100% sure that these modules are not used by any component of your system you can do it in a *hacky* way. Only if you patch the feature’s `.info` dependencies and then revert it.

If it’s not very important to disable these modules (let’s say conflict with something?) do not do that!